# Code to display alternating upper and lower-case returns lower-case only?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, methods

I am trying to write a function that displays a string as alternating upper and lower case letters.

For example:

```
str= "My name is ballouta!"
==> My NaMe Is BaLlOuTa!
```

My code is:

```
def alt_case
flag = 0
str = ''
self.scan(/./) do |b|
  if flag == 0
    b.upcase ; 
    flag = 1
    str = str + b

  else
    b.downcase
    flag = 0
    str =  str + b

  end #end if

end #end do
str
end #end method
```

This code returns the string as lower-case ONLY.

Comment: You want `b.upcase!` and `b.downcase!`, not `b.upcase` and `b.downcase`.

Comment: You should edit to put `class String` at the beginning and `end` at the end.  After adding the `!` ("bang") to `upcase` and `downcase` your code will work, but it could be made more Ruby-like and improved quite a bit.

Comment: `"My name is ballouta!".chars.map.with_index { |ch,i| i.even? ? ch.upcase : ch }.join # => "My nAmE Is bAlLoUtA!"` if whitespaces included in the alternation

Answer (score 3):

```
"My name is ballouta!"
.gsub(/\w/).with_index{|s, i| i.even? ? s.upcase : s.downcase}
# => "My NaMe Is BaLlOuTa!"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `upcase` and `downcase`, both of which return the altered value (which you are not saving and using).

The in-place alternatives `upcase!` and `downcase!` may help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I see @bjhaid suggested pretty much the same solution as mine in a comment well before I posted this. I'll leave my answer up for the explanation I've provided.

Now that your question has been answered, let me suggest a way to change your code to make it more Ruby-like:

```
class String
  def alt_case
    split.map { |w| w.chars.map.with_index{ |s,i|
      i.even? ? s.upcase : s.downcase }.join }.join(' ')
  end
end

"My name is ballouta!".alt_case #=> "My NaMe Is BaLlOuTa!"
```

Here's how this works:

```
self           #=> "My name is ballouta!" (default receiver)
a = self.split #=> ["My", "name", "is", "ballouta!"]
b = a.map { |w| w.chars.map.with_index{ |s,i|
      i.even? ? s.upcase : s.downcase }.join }
               #=> ["My", "NaMe", "Is", "BaLlOuTa!"]
b.join(' ')    #=> "My NaMe Is BaLlOuTa!"
```

When computing `b`, consider the case when `w => "name"`:

```
c = w.chars    #=> ["n", "a", "m", "e"] 
d = c.map.with_index{ |s,i| i.even? ? s.upcase : s.downcase }
               #=> ["N", "a", "M", "e"] 
d.join         #=> "NaMe"
```

I added this method to the String class only because that's what you've done, but in general I wouldn't recommend that; `alt_case(string)` would be fine.